# Which icon sizes to use with a JFrame's setIconImages() method?

Tags: java, icons, size, jframe, frame

Does anyone know which icon sizes to use with the setIconImages() (PLURAL) method for a jFrame so that my app icons display well on all platforms and in all contexts (e.g., window icon, taskbar icon, alt-tab icon, etc.)?

I've found an example that uses a 16px-by-16px and a 32px-by-32px image, but do I need to go any bigger?

To test, I have also tried adding 64px and 128px versions to the List passed to setIconImages(), but these do not seem to be used on my Windows 7 machine. However, I cannot test easily on other machines, so am wondering if anyone knows which sizes I should include?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the API the runtime chooses the most appropriate size to use from the list supplied. I would supply `16x16`, `32x32`, `64x64` and `128x128` and let the JVM decide at runtime.

> `public void` [`setIconImages`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages%28java.util.List%29)`(`[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)`<? extends`[`Image`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)`> icons)`
>
> Sets the sequence of images to be displayed as the icon for this window. Subsequent calls to getIconImages will always return a copy of the `icons` list.
>
> Depending on the platform capabilities one or several images of different dimensions will be used as the window's icon.
>
> The `icons` list is scanned for the images of most appropriate dimensions from the beginning. If the list contains several images of the same size, the first will be used.
>
> Ownerless windows with no icon specified use platfrom-default icon. The icon of an owned window may be inherited from the owner unless explicitly overridden. Setting the icon to null or empty list restores the default behavior.
>
> Note : Native windowing systems may use different images of differing dimensions to represent a window, depending on the context (e.g. window decoration, window list, taskbar, etc.). They could also use just a single image for all contexts or no image at all.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `icons` - the list of icon images to be displayed.
>
> **Since:**
>
> 1.6
>
> **See Also:**
>
> [`getIconImages()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getIconImages%28%29), [`setIconImage(Image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29)