# JFrame Icon Resolution

Tags: java, image, jframe, resolution

I'm quite new to working with java GUIs. To start me up, I had a look into JFrame. While playing around with it, I used the setIconImage() method to set the logo of my JFrame. However, when I run the file, the logo resolution gets reduced so much that I can barely recognise it. Here's my current code and the dimensions of my image is 1280 x 1280 (I have tried reducing it down to 100 x 100 but it still returned the same results.):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GUIManager extends JFrame{
        public void openGUI(String value){
            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("startMenu")){
                GUIManager manager = new GUIManager();
                ImageIcon logo = new
                ImageIcon(ResourcesLoader.class.getResource("Logo.png"));

                manager.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                manager.setVisible(true);
                manager.setResizable(false);
                manager.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                manager.setSize(300, 500);
                manager.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                manager.setTitle("FileLocker");
                manager.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
            } //value check
        } //openGUI
    } //GUIManager
```

Comment: Could you please specify a bit more clearly, what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given Before go to following link

[Sizes of frame icons used in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18224184/sizes-of-frame-icons-used-in-swing)

[Which icon sizes to use with a JFrame's setIconImages() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247653/which-icon-sizes-to-use-with-a-jframes-seticonimages-method)