# The icon autoscaling doesn't work very well in Java using Swing

Tags: java, swing

Apparently windows developers knew what they're doing when they invented the multisized `.ico` format. The problem is that rescaling images smoothly is very expensive and if it's not smooth, it looks like you know what. And if you don't, have a look:

[image: image description]

As the image shows, the icon scaled by Swing looks as crappy as the one scaled with MSPaint, while GIMP scales it beautifully. My question therefore is:

What's the best solution to display the icon nicely in Java, Swing - even if the original icon resolution is huge (250x250 in this case)?

Should I distribute multiple icons with multiple sizes? Can I use Windows icon that supports multiscale? Can I enable better scaling methods in Swing?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247653/which-icon-sizes-to-use-with-a-jframes-seticonimages-method) may help

Comment: @Reimeus I wasn't aware of this method. Yet, does it also work for tray icon?